# Why is the *ngFor loop in the code segment not being entered?

Tags: angular

The following ngFor loop is never entered even though the array subBanner1 contains data:

```
<div class="col-6 d-flex d-lg-flex flex-column justify-content-lg-center shop-all"
        *ngFor="let image of images.subBanner1">
        <img class="img-fluid d-lg-flex" src="assets/img/{{image}}" alt="image">
    </div>
```

this is the subBanner1 array:

```
subBanner1: ['05-0320-w1-Women-Main2.jpg', '05-0320-w1-Men-Main2.jpg']
```

On the other hand when I directly target a specific element of the array as shown below, it does display the image.

```
<div class="col-6 d-flex d-lg-flex flex-column justify-content-lg-center shop-all">
        <img class="img-fluid d-lg-flex" src="assets/img/{{images.subBanner1[0]}}">
    </div>
```

Code that obtains the subBanner1 array:

```
private getHomeStaticData = () => {
const homeSelector = (state) => {return (state.home)};
let home$ = this.store.select(homeSelector);

home$.subscribe(homeStaticData => {
  this.images = homeStaticData.images
  console.log('images', this.images)
  console.log('images.subBanner1', this.images.subBanner1)
})    
 }
```

subBanner1 initialization:

```
const initialState = {
    images: {
        mainBanner: '05-0320-w1-HeroClearout2.jpg',
        subBanner1: ['05-0320-w1-Women-Main2.jpg', '05-0320-w1-Men-Main2.jpg']
    }
   }
```

Comment: Are you using the `OnPush` strategy?

Comment: I don't know what the OnPush strategy is. Is it a new Angular construct?

Comment: Instead of the `<img>`, can you try to print all elements out?

Comment: No, it's a property in the component decorator. Can you please add the code where you populate the array?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have added the code that obtains the array.

Comment: @koque have a look at Roy's answer, he's right.

Comment: @koque - Can you add an element like `<div>Image: {{image}}</div>` as a child of the parent `div`? That would help to determine if the problem is with the loop or with the image element.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not using the indexing strategy inside the `*ngFor`

```html
<div class="col-6 d-flex d-lg-flex flex-column justify-content-lg-center shop-all"
    *ngFor="let image of images.subBanner1; index as i">
    <img class="img-fluid d-lg-flex" src="assets/img/{{image[i]}}" alt="image">
</div>
```

The `index as i` was added to provide your array an index. Also added the `{{image[i]}}` which will have the corresponding index when looping through the array of images.

Read more about all local variables you can have inside your `*ngFor` in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables).

---

**Edit**
After some debugging, I think above is not the way to go, as what I can see from what you're providing inside your question, you're actually not assigning the array to `subBanner1`. It should be `=`, not `:`.

```js
subBanner1: ['05-0320-w1-Women-Main2.jpg', '05-0320-w1-Men-Main2.jpg']
```

should be

```js
subBanner1 = ['05-0320-w1-Women-Main2.jpg', '05-0320-w1-Men-Main2.jpg']
```

I made [a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbycbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to show above modification and to see what the actual problem was.

Comment: Didn't work. The problem is the ngFor loop is not being entered so even if I target the image by index the loop is still not entered.

Comment: @Roy - Isn't `image` already pointing to the array item? Why appending an index to it? I would understand `{{images.subBanner1[i]}}` but I don't understand `{{image[i]}}`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yeah, I think you're right. Let me set something straight.

Comment: @Roy Your code works but it does not solve my problem. If I remove the index from your code like this: <div *ngFor="let image of bannerArray" style="border: 1px solid red;">, it still works. And this is exactly what I am doing in my code without the index. For some reason neither is working for me. I have implemented ngFor as shown in my code hundreds of times and they worked. I am beginning to think this has to do with the latest version of Angular.

Comment: Did you read my edit fully? It mentions the array assignment.

Comment: @Roy subBanner1 is properly initialized. It is a property of an NgRx object. I have included the initialization in my original question.